# Receiving an e mail of visitors informations when they fill up the forms

Tags: php, forms, email

I got to solve this problem..So I have a forms on my website(html/css/js) and I would like to receive an E-mail once a customer fill it up instead of the registation in a  DB .I m a beginner in php and  i hope u'll help me ..below is my PHP code.

```
<?php

// Define some constants
define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "my name " );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "******@***.com" );

// Read the form values
$success = false;
$userName = isset( $_POST['username'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\s\S\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['username'] ) : "";
$lastName = isset( $_POST['lastname'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\s\S\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['lastname'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['email'] ) : "";
$userPhone = isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\s\S\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['phone'] ) : "";
$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Phone:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $userName && $lastName && $senderEmail && $userPhone && $message) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
  $headers = "From: " . $userName . "";
  $msgBody = " Last Name: ". $lastName .  " Email: ". $senderEmail . " Phone: ". $userPhone . " Message: " . $message . "";
  $success = mail( $recipient, $headers, $msgBody );

  //Set Location After Successsfull Submission
  header('Location: contact.html?message=Successfull');
}

else{
    //Set Location After Unsuccesssfull Submission
    header('Location: contact.html?message=Failed');    
}

?>
```

Comment: you have stated what u are doing, please state the problem that you are facing along with the error message

Comment: I don't get any errors but I don't receive anything on my email

Comment: did you setup your SMTP server in `php.ini`

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you use the library [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for the sending of the E-Mails.
An E-Mail needs to be configured and PHPMailer does that automatically.

Comment: where Should I put the PHPMailer  library??